# implementing Comparator to Compare two Objects

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to implement Comparator that compare object1 and object2 where these two objects are complex objects(nested objects).

My requirement is that if there is any null value in object2 and corresponding value in object1 is null or not null then my comparator should return true but if value in object2 is not null and curresponding value in object 1 is different or null then it should return false.

These values may be of object inside object so on or of base object.

Can you please suggest me how should I implement compareTo() method so that I get my desire result.

Comment: Where is the issue ? Show some code .

Comment: Do you expect that people here will write logic for you? Paste your code you and show that you have worked on this problem and ask specific problem.

Comment: I was doing by reflection. I got stuck at a point and it was my mistake that I didn't post code too. But I got the solution while I was doing. It could 1h to solve the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the compareTo method don't return true or false
a comparator work usually:
it returns -1 if the first given object is smaller than the second one
it returns 1 if the first given object is bigger than the second one
and it returns 0 if the objects are even

that would be something like (considering you want to compare two objects based on the strings in them):

```
if (a.getString() == null && a.getString() == null) {
        return 0;    //both of them are null: return  equal
    }
    if (a.getString() == null) {
        return 1;    //first one is null: second is bigger
    }
    if (b.getString() == null) {
        return -1;   //second one is null: first is bigger
    }
    return a.getString().compareTo(b.getString()); //compare the two strings 
                                                   //inside, with the already 
                                                   //existing method from the 
                                                   //String class
```

considering you didn't give any code example, this code would match your needs

Comment: I was doing by reflection. I got stuck at a point and it was my mistake that I didn't post code too. But I got the solution while I was doing. It could 1h to solve the problem. Thanks